# Python Character Encoding Inconsistency Between Environments

Tags: python, encoding, character, rhel

Server Error: 
python 2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "promoter.py", line 325, in process_unfollowbacks
    self.add_user_to_database(user_info)
  File "promoter.py", line 618, in add_user_to_database
    str(u['name']),
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, it runs on Ubuntu fine.

Server:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar  2 2014, 10:09:03) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Ubuntu:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I'm getting this error by operating on a dictionary resulting from a Twitter Json array (Twython module) however I don't think the fault is there.

A little inspection shows this is happening with foreign languages.

The Question:
**How do I deal with this inconsistency between environments?**

Answer (score 0):

The default encoding in your 'Server' environment is not the same as the Ubuntu environment.  Try u['name'].encode('utf-8')

Comment: .encode('utf-8') was the first thing I did, however even that throws errors.

Comment: What does this yield? print '%r' % u['name']